# PHP Fatal Error; call to undefined function for a user-defined function

Tags: php

is there a reason why i'm getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function iptocountry()

on line  `$two_letter_country_code=iptocountry($ip);`

UPDATE: I moved `$two_lettter_country_code=ipcountry($ip)`
to the bottom.

Now i'm getting this error:

> Warning: include(/ip_files/::1.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory

How do I remove the `::` before the number?

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else
    $ip   = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


function iptocountry($ip)
{
    $numbers = preg_split( "/\./", $ip);    

    include("/ip_files/".$numbers[0].".php");
    $code=($numbers[0] * 16777216) + ($numbers[1] * 65536) + ($numbers[2] * 256) + ($numbers[3]);    

    foreach($ranges as $key => $value)
    {
        if($key<=$code)
        {
            if($ranges[$key][0]>=$code)
            {
                $country=$ranges[$key][1];break;

        }
    }

    if ($country=="")
    {
        $country="unknown";
    }

    return $country;
}

$two_letter_country_code=iptocountry($ip);

if ($two_letter_country_code=="US")
  die();
```

include file : is named 0 through 200

```
<?php
//0-16777215
$ranges=Array(
"0" => array("16777215","ZZ"),
);
?>
```

Comment: **First** define a function, **then** call it.

Comment: You're calling the function before its been declared.  Move your function call below the declaration.

Comment: Is this the complete code? Because [I cannot reproduce the error](https://3v4l.org/S32ag)

Comment: yes its the complete code, its going in the header of a wordpress site

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with the complete code either: https://3v4l.org/6eCMe

Comment: This cannot possibly be the complete (and unmodified) code - at the very least, you're missing the `<?php` opening tag ... that's on top of the code being perfectly valid otherwise, so something *is* missing from it.

Comment: this is being added to the wordpress header, Is it something in wordpres?

Comment: Re: your update, you're likely getting an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From PHP documentation on [User-defined functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, *except* when a function is conditionally defined as shown in the two examples below.

To say it more accurately, function declarations are "hoisted" (you can use them before their declaration) when they are declared inside the global space (i. e. not inside an other function), but only in this case.

Your code would work in global space, but it is probably inside a function, hence the [forward reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration#Forward_reference) error.

To illustrate, the following code correctly calls `global_function` but gets an "undefined function" error trying to call `also_global`:

```
global_function();

function global_function()
{
    also_global();

    function also_global()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: The function is not defined within the conditional in this case though.

Comment: As long as we're saying "probably", my money is on the function being declared by an `include()`.

Comment: Indeed, there don't need a conditional, it just has to be in another function. The PHP documentation is perfectible on this point. I added an example to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you are calling the function before declaring.

It is better to define your functions which you may use in other PHP scripts in a separate file like `helpers.php` and on top of your PHP script write `require_once helper.php` so you can use your functions wherever you want.